# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

Tags: php

Estoy practicando programación por primera ves y no entiendo mucho del tema, cuestión, que me esta saltando un error, el error es el siguiente:

> Notice: Undefined variable: insertar in C:\xampp\htdocs\LibrosParaTodos\php\configuracionControl.php on line 26

```
$id=$_POST['id'];

        $value=$_POST['checkbox'];

        if(is_array($_POST['checkbox'])){
            while (list($key,$value)= var_dump(each($_POST['checkbox']))){
                $insertar=mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO libroscontrol(idUsuarios,idGeneroLibros) VALUES('$id','$value')");
            }
        }   
        **if($insertar){
            $alerta="<div class='alert alert-success mt-6'><i class='far fa-check-circle'></i> La configuracion fue creada con exito</div>";
        }else{
            $alerta="<div class='alert alert-danger mt-6'><i class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Nose se logro la configuracion de la seleccion de control parental</div>";        
        }**
```

Lo que esta resaltado es donde estaría el error, pero se supone que la variable esta definida arriba (o es lo que creo), como lo arreglo?

Comment: Tienes que inicializar la variable afuera del `if`.

Comment: ¿como con los post de checkbox y id?

Comment: Exactamente asi

Comment: muchas gracias, ya pude arreglar el problema

Comment: Prueba con isset()

Es decir if (isset($insertar))

Answer (score 1):

Puedes inicializar tu variable `$insertar` en `false` para que si el proceso ha ido bien, se vuelva `true`

```
$insertar=false;
```

Comment: problema solucionado, gracias